# Where can I find documentation on the /etc/environment file format?

Tags: environment-variables

From [System-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide%20environment%20variables):

> - **/etc/environment** - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.

I'm looking for an [ABNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) and/or a more detailed description of behaviour, or anything that isn't forum hearsay really.

*If it's on Google, it's eluding me.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isn't made more clear, but `/etc/environment` isn't parsed by any single bit of code or any particular shell (or necessarily any shell at all) (try `grep -r "/etc/environment" /etc` and you'll see what I mean). `pam` in particular parses it directly, not putting it through a shell.

By convention, and I do mean *convention*, it's pure key-value pairs, with values optionally quoted. You can't put anything that tries to do e.g. variable expansion or command execution in there and expect it to work.

I'd be surprised if you can find a strict, formal grammar definition anywhere.

Probably the closest to an authoritative answer you can come is the `pam_env` docs: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html

Comment: That's what "it is not a script file" is supposed to mean. But I guess a lot of people don't realise.

Answer (score 3):

You can find good information in the **environ** man page.
It is accessible from a terminal, by typing  **`man 7 environ`** in it.

> By convention the strings in environ have the form "name=value".

You can also read it from your browser: **http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man7/environ.7.html#toptoc2**

And it gives you some examples of usage and more details.

Comment: Note that the environ(7) man page documents the format of the environment of a process, in the C API. The file `/etc/environment` is used to fill the environment of a process, but it has its own syntactic rules, as explained by Nicholas.