# Add path to PATH environment variable for www-data

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I'm trying to add `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux` to the `PATH` environment for my Apache user (`www-data`) after installing TeX Live 2012 manually.

I edited my `/etc/environment`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux"
```

to include this path within my system-wide `PATH` environment variable for all users.

However, if I execute `sudo -u www-data printenv PATH` I'm only getting:

```
# sudo -u www-data printenv PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I can't understand the source of this issue and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem where I needed a specific export for www-data to use when running PHP exec command and managed to cobble together this solution:

- Edit `/etc/apache2/envvars`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
  ```

  - Add your export to the end of the file and save it.

    ```
    export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux"
    ```
  - Restart Apache:

    ```
    sudo service apache2 restart
    ```

Now if you execute the following PHP

```
<?php
    $descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
       1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
       2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
    );
    $process = proc_open('env', $descriptorspec, $pipes, dirname(__FILE__), null);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    var_dump($stdout);
?>
```

You should see your environmental path as set in the file. It seems that apache spawns commands under www-data using the contents of that config file only and not from and of the bash.bashrc etc type files? I Can't say for certain because I'm new to Linux.

Not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to achieve but hope it helps.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache 2.2.22 `/etc/init.d/apache2` has the following:

    ENV="env -i LANG=C PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
    if [ "$APACHE_CONFDIR" != /etc/apache2 ] ; then
     ENV="$ENV APACHE_CONFDIR=$APACHE_CONFDIR"
    fi
    if [ "$APACHE_ENVVARS" != "$APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars" ] ; then
     ENV="$ENV APACHE_ENVVARS=$APACHE_ENVVARS"
    fi

This overrides anything in `/etc/environment` and suggests that `/etc/apache2/envvars` is the best place to add/edit vars required globally for apache. You can set environment vars locally within a `VirtualHost` config using `SetEnv`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it looks like it's only `LANG` and `PATH` that are set in this way, so any other vars added to `/etc/environment` are included just fine.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I add `export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/owncloud` (which works manually as `www-data`) but it has no effect after service restart. Also tried with out `export`..

Comment: @George is parcial right, forgetting that www-data user can be used also for running services, so editing trough apache won't work. Sometimes the user needs some specific vars, for e.g. to run dotnet

Answer (score 3):

Your `/etc/environment` doesn't need the `export` statement in front of the key/value pairs. As stated in the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables):

> It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

See [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-the-etc-environment-file-format) on how the format works.

Comment: I know, I tried both variants, but none of them worked out. In my case it was sufficient to add the additional path to `/etc/apache2/envvars`. However, a `sudo -u www-data printenv PATH` still does not recognize the additional path using `/etc/environmnent`, so the original question is no solved.